# Dynamically created custom control in wpf and it's values

Tags: wpf, dynamic, controls

I create my custom control which contains only root stackpanel and which have only one dependency property called param1. Whenever param1 changes I dynamically add to stackpanel some textboxes or comboboxes or mix of them.

Now simulate the behaviour: In my window I create that custom control and when I choose param1 ,I have for ex. 3 textboxes and 2 comboboxes. I fill them with my values for example "1","2","3","4","5".

Now when I click button which is part of my window, I want to get all that values and use them somewhere.

What is the best way to do that?

My first idea is to keep these comboboxes and textboxes in two lists in my control and later just recover it from that list and get values. But there must be better idea than doing something like that.

Any ideas?

Comment: If it is in the StackPanel then you can loop through the children and get the values.

Comment: Do you need to dynamically add these children to your custom control? Any way you look at it, you are going to have to evaluate the children to pull the right value. The alternative approach would be to have a set of known responses to your param1 and hide/show different children based on the selection. This would allow you to make use of databinding.

Comment: Don't create or manipulate UI elements in code in WPF or any other XAML based UI technology. Learn MVVM and do it with an `ItemsControl` in any case.

Comment: Thanks Dilshod, that definitely better idea.

Comment: HighCore I know MVVM but can't imagine how do you want to use to get something like this with ItemsControl ?

Comment: @Zbigniew post a screenshot of what you need and I can tell you the proper way to do it in WPF. If you can't post images here in Stackoverflow, try `imgur.com`.